# Не отображается изображение .png при запуске приложения в эмуляторе Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-constraintlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="319dp"
        android:layout_height="327dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mainLogo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvText"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

В предпросмотре изображение показывается, но как только запускаю в эмуляторе, изображение пропадает. Пробовал добавлять изображение прописывая код и вручную через Design, результат один.
В другом приложении код ImageView прописан аналогично и работает.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:text="@string/C"
        android:fontFamily="@font/intelone_mono_font_family_regular"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="292dp"
        android:layout_height="304dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvText"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pythagor"
        android:contentDescription="ImageOfTheoreme" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
```

Мб кто сталкивался и знает как решить, заранее спасибо

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы растягиваете `tvText` на весь `parent`, возможно ваше изображение просто под ним. Во втором случае разметка иная, растягивания нет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но дело оказалось не в этом. Я заменил app:srcCompat на android:src и все сработало